# How to store json_data inside pallet runtime?

Tags: oracles, acurast

I am using `Acurast` to bring off-chain data into on-chain. I have created job and decode data inside `fn on_fulfillment` like [this](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/tanssi/blob/1326ba225e248544ed654bfb9bd242c999b3f787/container-chains/templates/simple/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1018),

```
pub struct OnAcurastFulfillment;
impl pallet_acurast_fulfillment_receiver::traits::OnFulfillment<Runtime> for OnAcurastFulfillment {
    fn on_fulfillment(
        _from: <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        _fulfillment: Fulfillment,
    ) -> DispatchResultWithInfo<PostDispatchInfo> {
        // fulfillment.payload contains the bytes processed by the script
        
        let company_response: u128 =
            parity_scale_codec::decode_from_bytes(_fulfillment.payload.into()).unwrap_or_default();

        Ok(().into())
    }
}
```

If it is just single value, then I can store like this.

```
// if it is a storage value
<pallet_price::Price<Runtime>>::put(price); // u32
```

But in my case return value is like this,

```
{
    "company_number": "SC122423",
    "auth_code": "901594",
    "company_uri": "https://api-sandbox.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/SC122423"
}
```

How can I store this json response?

**Edit**

```
{
    "links": {
        "filing_history": "/company/SC908250/filing-history",
        "officers": "/company/SC908250/officers",
        "persons_with_significant_control_statement": "/company/SC908250/persons-with-significant-control-statement",
        "self": "/company/SC908250"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "next_due": "2025-09-12",
        "next_accounts": {
            "period_start_on": "2023-12-12",
            "period_end_on": "2024-12-12",
            "due_on": "2025-09-12",
            "overdue": false
        },
        "next_made_up_to": "2024-12-12",
        "accounting_reference_date": {
            "day": "12",
            "month": "12"
        },
        "overdue": false
    },
    "company_number": "SC908250",
    "date_of_creation": "2022-12-12",
    "type": "ltd",
    "undeliverable_registered_office_address": false,
    "company_name": "COMPANY SC908250 LIMITED",
    "sic_codes": [
        "71200"
    ],
    "confirmation_statement": {
        "next_made_up_to": "2024-12-12",
        "overdue": false,
        "next_due": "2024-12-26"
    },
    "registered_office_is_in_dispute": false,
    "company_status": "active",
    "etag": "43eeb07eb23fbcb8a0701db7a7e694f83877f55d",
    "has_insolvency_history": false,
    "registered_office_address": {
        "premise": "1",
        "address_line_1": "4th Floor Edinburgh Quay 2",
        "address_line_2": "139 Fountain Bridge",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "locality": "Edinburgh",
        "postal_code": "EH3 9FF"
    },
    "jurisdiction": "scotland",
    "has_charges": false,
    "can_file": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a struct to represent this JSON.

```rs
#[derive(Encode, Decode)]
struct S {
  company_number: Vec<u8>,
  autho_code: Vec<u8>,
  company_uri: Vec<u8>,
}
```

2. Store it as a `Vec<u8>`. Convert it to bytes first using `base64()`, `as_bytes()`, or any other method you prefer.